# Did angel Gabriel come to Abdullah and Ameena the parents of the prophet and proclaim to them that they shall keep the name Muhammad for their son

Tags: malaikah, names

As Salam Aleikhum  I am very curious In the bible and torah it is mentioned that many prophets the well known of them isaac ishmael john and jesus
peace and blessings of Allah be on them all were given names form Allah by sending angel Gabriel to the parents to pronounce the name so my quetion is this even
though it is written in ancient scriptures that a prophet will come whose name will be Ahmad or Muhammad How did the parents Abdulha and Ameena keep the name Muhammad
or Ahmad did angel Gabriel come to the parents and anounce proclaim to them you shall name this child Muhammad for Allah has chosen this name Muhammad as it was
like that in the case of most prophets in bible and torah in the quran also it is mentioned about angel Gabriel comming down and anouncing names at that time also the name Muhammad was very new
ven I wouldnt have taught of the name if I was livng then Jazak Allahu Khair forgive me for my curiosity